# expanding a C# console app to a WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application

What's the best way to convert a simple console application to a WPF? and I am a COMPLETE newb so be gentle!! 
The console app displays information according to user choices.. real simple stuff, but I'd like to create a GUI for it in WPF.. and am looking for initial steps on how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://ejadib.wordpress.com/2006/12/14/windows-presentation-foundation-wpf-hello-world/), and [this](http://www.microsoft.com/uk/msdn/nuggets/nugget/68/Hello-World-Introduction-to-WPF.aspx) (video) might be worth checking out. They will get you started with building a WPF app, you'll need to figure out how to port your existing interface to WPF though, which might not be very straight forward because there is a large shift in building a console app (Console.WriteLine/Console.Read) and a GUI app with GUI objects with events and display properties.

I recommend jumping in with the links above and positing additional questions here when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to think how the new interface will behave. A gui is different from console interaction.
Draw on paper the gui you want, buttons, text areas, etc.
Think about the logic and it should behave, i.e. wizard like, button interaction, etc.

Only then approach the implementation in WPF, for that look for some beginner tutorial, like [ths](http://www.wpftutorial.net/)